# What‘s meaning of stripslashes( $pass ) in php

Tags: php, sql, stripslashes

When I was learing Brute Force in DVWA, I read the High Brute Force Source. It use `stripslaches( $user );` function before use `mysql_real_escape_string( $user );` function. I know `mysql_real_escape_string()` can escape special character so that it is safe in SQL statement.
But I don't understand the function `stripslaches()`. Does it also make a safe SQl statement?

Comment: 3 votes for that duplicate? You've got to scroll to about the 7th answer before there's even a mention of `stripslashes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripslashes()` is useless in any SQL context.  The only thing it's good for is undoing the evil effects of magic quotes on servers with broken configurations that you don't have access to change.